# How to group by two different fields

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

The structure of documents from my collection looks as follows:

```
    [

    {
    sender: 'A', recipient: 'B', date: New MongoDate(1), contents: 'Blablabla1'
    },

    {
    sender: 'B', recipient: 'A', date: New MongoDate(2), contents: 'Blablabla2'
    },

    {
    sender: 'A', recipient: 'C', date: New MongoDate(4), contents: 'Blablabla1'
    },

    {
    sender: 'C', recipient: 'A', date: New MongoDate(3), contents: 'Blablabla2' 
    }

    {
    sender: 'C', recipient: 'D', date: New MongoDate(3), contents: 'Blablabla2'
    }


    ]
```

I would like to group by recipient or sender and select from each group only one document that has the largest date

For example, I would like to obtain such a result:

```
[

{
_id: 'AB', sender: 'B', recipient: 'A', date: 2, contents: 'Blablabla2', count: 2
},

{
_id: 'AC', sender: 'A', recipient: 'C',  date: 4, contents: 'Blablabla1', count: 2
}

{
_id: 'CD', sender: 'C', recipient: 'D',  date: 3, contents: 'Blablabla2', count: 1
}

]
```

How to do it? I do not know how to group by two different fields..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you try this aggregation

1. `$sort` - to sort by date to take the `$last` element in `$group`
2. `$group` - to group by `$cond` _id and `$concat` by alphabetical order
3. `$sort` - to sort result by `_id` in ascending

pipeline

```
db.col.aggregate(
    [
        {$sort : { date : 1}},
        {$group : {
            _id : { $cond : [ {$gt : ["$sender", "$recipient"]}, {$concat : ["$recipient", "$sender"]}, {$concat : ["$sender", "$recipient"]}]},
            sender : {$last : "$sender"},
            recipient : {$last : "$recipient"},
            date : {$last : "$date"},
            contents : {$last : "$contents"},
            count : {$sum : 1}
         }
        },
        {$sort : { _id : 1}},
    ]
)
```

result

```
{ "_id" : "AB", "sender" : "B", "recipient" : "A", "date" : 2, "contents" : "Blablabla2", "count" : 2 }
{ "_id" : "AC", "sender" : "A", "recipient" : "C", "date" : 4, "contents" : "Blablabla1", "count" : 2 }
{ "_id" : "CD", "sender" : "C", "recipient" : "D", "date" : 3, "contents" : "Blablabla2", "count" : 1 }
>
```

Comment: That's what I meant. You are genius. Thanks.